# dom parse of twitter search for older tweets,

Tags: web-scraping

*i want to dom parse of twitter search for older tweets,

on first first {search it gives maximum 20 results,
 my problem is next when i scroll down next result comes.

i am not finding any links on mouse hoever.
 i am thinking use of browser automation but not finding any useful link on mouse hoever tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this can be done using selenium browser automation .